# Repeating a cartesian product on a fixed RDD

Tags: python, loops, pyspark, rdd, cartesian-product

I am into trouble to understand the cartesian method from the pyspark api. It returns the cartesian product of 2 RDD in a new RDD.
I want to apply this method to 2 RDD in a loop (on a fixed RDD and another always different, but always with the same size). I don't figured out why the size of the RDD is multiplied by the size of the second RDD at each iteration (as if the cartesian product was stacked with previous result).
This lead to an indefinite execution and heavy ressource allocation...

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, sc, max_iter=100):
        self.spark = sc
        self.data = None
        self.max_iter = max_iter

    def calc(self, rdd):
        combinations = self.data.cartesian(rdd)\
            .map(lambda row: do_something(row))
        lists = combinations.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
        res = lists.map(lambda row: do_something_else(row))
        return res

    def gen(self, rdd):
        return rdd.map(lambda row: do_something_again(row)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)\
            .map(lambda row: do_a_last_thing(row))

    def run(self, rdd):
        self.data = rdd.persist()
        self.data.localCheckpoint()
        iteration = 0
        results = self.calc(rdd.takeSample(False, 3))
        while self.max_iter > iteration:
            tmp = gen(results)
            results = self.calc(tmp)
            iteration += 1
        return results.collect()
```

This class is called in another python script :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
test = MyClass(spark)
data = RandomRDDs.normalVectorRDD(spark, 10, 5, 3)
result = test.run(data)
print(result)
```

I don't know if this is due to the python classes stucture or an implementation error.
I tried to make the fixed RDD persistent and to create a local checkpoint (in the case it was due to lineage relashionships), but none of these works.
Do someone ever tried to use the cartesian method in a loop ?

Comment: cartesian will give you all possible combinations of pairs created by selecting one value from RDD A, and one value from RDD B.  The final RDD will always be size of the two multiplied.  In other words "result_length = rdd_a.count x rdd_b.count".  If that isn't what you wanted, what behavior do you want?

Comment: The problem is that the size of the cartesian product that I want to calculate should not increase with each iteration. It must remain the same size as the two input RDDs multiplied (which always have the same size).

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a cartesian join then.  A cartesian join will by definition increase the number of rows since it is all combinations.  If you want a one-one join then you probably want a inner join on some key (function is just RDD.join).

Comment: I have a fixed RDD of dimension N and another RDD of dimension M.
What I want is to calculate the cartesian product of both at each iteration which means a RDD of dimension N.M (N & M are constant). But right now, I calculate a RDD of dimension N.M.i at each iteration which is basicly an infinite loop...
Here is the full code because I noticed it wasn't clear : https://gist.github.com/belgacea/f5028fce2cbe5828367d927ca7dc26f7#file-kmeans-py-L82